# Visual Studio 2022 Installer Closes

Tags: installation

Since yesterday my Visual Studios 2022 doesn't work anymore, so I deinstalled it and now when I try to install it the Installer loads says downloading installing after that the two bars are Green and it closes and nothing happens. I already tried deleting the folder, Turning off Firewall, tried to start vs_installer.exe nothing happens. After that I tried to install Visual Studio 2019 same thing happens. Last Windows update was on the 21.06.2022 Anyone got an Idea what else i should try?

Answer (score 0):

I've just had this problem installing VS2022 Pro on a Windows 11 VM running in Parallels. I tried everything and eventually turned off Microsoft's Real-time Protection in Virus & Threat Protection Settings. It's installing now.